# replace or remove some special characters in string only from starting and ending , not from in between of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, logic

replace or remove some special characters (-) in string only from starting and ending , not from in between of string in javascript.

the string is fully dynamic , count of special characters (-) at starting and ending will be different every time , and the string will also change every time , so we have to develop dynamic logic.

ex.

```
original string = "-----hello--stack--over--flowj-----"
output string = "hello--stack--over--flowj"
```

I have tried replace and substring methods , but i was unable to remove specifically starting and ending special character (-) , and for that I was thinking for loops and to count special characters (-) and that all.

Thank You.

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried and post your code. This will help in getting answers.

Comment: @Yeti ok i wil do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `replace()` function:

```
string.replace(/^-*|-*$/g,"")
```

Comment: Thank You!! , can you explain me this regex? and how specifically this [(/^-*|-*$/g,"")] regex works .!

Comment: @KaranShah it matches the `-` you described in your question. I suggest you reading some regex tutorial.